# overflow-y:scroll coming out of container

Tags: javascript, css

I am making a nodejs chat with socket.io and I am currently working on the overflow of the chat messages in the parent container. I'm having an issue with the overflow-y and the user messages, where the messages are not being hidden when they overflow, but continuing on past the input.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rHqv.png)

[codepen](https://codepen.io/pixelxii/pen/vbqbeN)

```
#main_container {
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
#inputs {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
}
```

It is most likely a dumb error on my part, and if so I apologize.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Unless you post your code in a [MCVE], nobody is going to be able to help you.

Comment: Just linking us to your project  is not a [mcve].    Read the link, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try it, change the property `position:absolute` for this `position:fixed`

```
#main_container {
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
#inputs {
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a height on the #main-container. Just specifying overflow-y: hidden is meaningless to a container with unbound height. If you want the chat window to take up the whole height of the screen minus a bit of space for the chat input at the bottom use

```
#main-container {
    overflow-y: auto, 
    height: calc(100vh - 100px)
}
```